# Button Styles not working in react native

Tags: react-native, button

I want to change button borderRadius,color, and padding but it doesn't work

this is my view

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer}  from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator}  from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
  return(
    <View
    style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button 
        style={styles.button}
        title= "Go To Details"
        onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

and this is my styles

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    width: 200,
    marginTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: "green",
    padding: 15,
    borderRadius: 50,
  },
});
```

this is my screen
[image]

are there something that i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so you can customize like your own with react native Button. But you can change something like title, color, etc. Check their doc https://reactnative.dev/docs/button

A better way is to make your own Button with your custom Style like this :

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Details')}>
  <View style={styles.button}>
   <Text>Go To Details</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Okay, i will try and come back here again

Comment: thanks, does anyone prefer this way for a button?

Comment: In react-native 0.63 you can also use the new component `Pressable` https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to use View, because button from 'react-native' have some default styling and there can be some difficulty to override them, you can customise View like anything you want. just have a View and give them desired styles.

```
function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
  return(
    <View
    style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <View 
        style={styles.button}
        title= "Go To Details"
        onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

just give styles you want

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    width: 200,
    marginTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: "green",
    padding: 15,
    borderRadius: 50,
  },
});
```

Comment: Okay, i will try and come back here again